# Groovy/Grails: How are constraints implemented?

Tags: validation, grails, groovy, closures, constraints

In the book, [Getting Started with Grails - 2e](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/grails-getting-started), page 42 (the electronic page, and not the paper page), the following example is listed.

```
class Race {

    static constraints = {

        name(blank:false, maxSize:50)


        // NOTE: This doesn’t do
        // what you think it does
        startDate(min: new Date())

        // And this is what we're supposed
        // to be using:
        // startDate(validator: {return (it > new Date())})
    }

    String name
    Date startDate
    // ...
}
```

The reader is then advised to use the version of `startDate` commented out above. The reason cited is: The `static constraints` property would get evaluated only once (at server startup time), whereas our intent is to have it evaluated on each instantiation and subsequent validation of `Race`.

**My question is:** Why then the non-closure style of the `name` constraint works on each validation attempt but not the `startDate` constraint? And, conversely, if the closure flavor is required for `startDate`, then why is it not required for `name` as well?

If I understand the above Groovy syntax correctly, it seems that each of the constraints listed in the `static constraint` block is, syntactically, a call to a function that takes various validation attributes as a `Map`. Now since the static block would get evaluated (once) at server startup time, both function calls too would happen (once) at the server startup time, and should lead to identical and consistent behavior in their non-closure form. **Isn't it so?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you go with:

```
    startDate(min: new Date())
```

Then `new Date()` will be evaluated at server start-time and will never change.  So next week (assuming the server keeps running) it will validate the date against last week.

The second form:

```
    startDate(validator: {return (it > new Date())})
```

Will be evaluated each time the constraint is checked, so it will always validate against today no matter how long the server has been running.

On the other hand, when `name` is concerned, it is validated against static content, viz `maxSize` being 50 which makes sense to have it as key value pair instead of using `validator` closure, since the value `50` is not evaluated everytime a validation is done on `name` as it is done for `startDate`.

#### Edit:

When the call `name( maxSize:50 )` call is evaluated, it actually creates a [`MaxSizeConstraint` object](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-core/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/validation/MaxSizeConstraint.java) for the field `name`. This map of `property->constraints` is then used by grails to check properties when the object is validated. As you can see in that class, `maxSize` is a private property.  Indeed, if you wanted `maxSize` to change over time, then you'd need to use a custom validator as with `Date`

Comment: I understand what you said so far. What I don't understand is this: The expression `new Date()` gets evaluted ONLY BECAUSE of the `startDate` function call, which happens at server startup. But the same should be true for `name` call also: that is, the `name` call should occur only once at server startup... but we KNOW that it gets evaluated on EACH validation. So, what is going on? Also, is my understanding of the Groovy syntax and semantics, that I shared above, right?

Comment: @Harry Have a look at the ending lines of answer.

Comment: Yes, I looked. Note that I fully understand the difference between the fixed value of `50` used for `name` and the dynamic `new Date()` value used for `startDate`. What I'm trying to know is, why the **function call** `name` occurs on each validation but the **function call** `startDate` only once? Meaning, if both function calls were made on each validation, then even the non-closure form of `startDate` would have sufficed.

Comment: @Harry added a bit more to hopefully help

Comment: @tim_yates I think, I get it now. What is happening is, though the function calls are happening only once consistently, Grails is storing the (side-)effect of those calls **somewhere** for later use. The side-effect for a 'size' type of constraint would be, by default, a once-instantiated `MaxSizeConstraint` object as a **property** whereas the side-effect of 'validator' type of property would be a **closure**, which would get evaluated every time. Can you please once again confirm this understanding of mine?

Comment: @Harry yep, that's it :-)  Of course, each property can have multiple constraints associated with it, so it's going to be a structure similar to `Map<String,List<Constraint>>` (in Java)

Comment: Thank a ton, Tim, for your prompt help. I'm happy now. Looks like, I'll have import the Grails and Groovy codebases in my Eclipse to be able to see what is going on (just like you could). Hope these codebases are Eclipse-friendly...

Answer (score 1):

I've done some experiments, and here are some conclusions. This is all empirical research; please, correct me if I am wrong.

First of all, it is easy to see, when the call to `constraints` gets evaluated. Just add some debug output:

```
static constraints = {
        println "Entering constraints..."
        name(blank:false, maxSize:50)
        // etc.
        println "Exiting constraints..."
}
```

You will see that it is indeed evaluated at application startup. For some reason that I don't understand, it is typically evaluated *twice*. Also notice that `constraints` is marked as *static*, so it has nothing to do with particular instances of the `class Race`.

Next, it is easy to find out that `name`, `startDate`, etc. are, indeed, function calls. Just try to specify constraints on a non-existing property:

```
static constraints = {
  no_such_thing(nullable:true)
}
```

You will not be able to do that! The result:

```
Error Error executing script Shell: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': 
       Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
     No signature of method: Race.no_such_thing() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[nullable:true]]
```

Of course, you have never defined all those methods, i.e. `name`, `startDate`, etc., and you haven't inherited your domain class from anything else either. But since Grails recognizes it as a domain class, it uses the power of Groovy to inject the methods into the object, bypassing the restrictions of traditional object-oriented programming.

Now, it doesn't literally inject the methods into the object. You can easily check:

```
static constraints = {
    println Race.metaClass.methods*.name.sort().unique()
    // You can even construct an object if you really want to mess with the framework
    println new Race().metaClass.methods*.name.sort().unique()
}
```

You will not see any methods called `name`, `startDate`, etc., and you can't `println Race.name` inside the `constraints { }` block either. What I think happens is that Groovy intercepts calls to nonexistent methods `Race.name`, `Race.startDate`, etc., and records this constraint information somewhere else for future use. If you want, try actually implementing methods called e.g. `Race.name`; I think I was able to prevent the constraints from working by doing so, but I can't reproduce it.

Regarding the question of what gets evaluated when, I think we have some confusion here about Groovy closures. Take a look at

```
startDate(validator: {return (it > new Date())})
```

Here we have a *closure*: `{return (it > new Date())}`. If Groovy were a pure interpreted language like Python, it would just store this literal code and reinterpret it on any and every call. Thus, you would also get the most current date. My guess is that Groovy mimics this behavior, even those the code is presumably compiled: it will wrap this code into a closure object, and will call this object every time validation is requested. This closure object will be stored **somewhere**; presumably, in the same place where all the other constraints are stored. The confusion arises because of the nature of closures: if you store `3`, it will always stay `3`; if you store a closure (a function), it can evaluate to different results on different occasions.

Just to reiterate, the code

```
{return (it > new Date())}
```

is not "executed" or "evaluated" on application startup; it is merely stored for future use. You can easily check it:

```
static constraints = {
    startDate(validator: {println "Validating startDate..."})
}
```

Then run `grails shell` and

```
groovy> (new Race()).validate()
```